# How is .NET Core able to support running on Windows, Linux and Mac operating systems?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

Let's say I have a class library which uses the `System.IO.StreamWriter` type in one of its classes and I have a `netcoreapp3.1` ASP.NET Core Web Application using this library.
I would like to run this web application on Windows, Linux and Mac operating systems.

Can somebody explain to me how things work under the hood when I call `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` method, for example?

- Are my calls to this method type forwarded to the 'appropriate' version of runtime? i.e

  1. On Windows a call to this method is forwarded to the .NET Core runtime of Windows's implementation of `netstandard` library?
  2. On Linux a call to this method is forwarded to the .NET Core runtime of Linux's implementation of `netstandard` library?
  3. On Windows a call to this method is forwarded to the **full .NET Framework(ex:4.7)** runtime of Windows's implementation of `netstandard` library? Let us assume I am referencing this class library from a .NET Framework 4.7 application too.
- Is this going to be similar in .NET 5 too? i.e if my class library is built using `net5.0` and is being used by a `.net5.0` ASP.NET web application and is run on Windows, Linux and Mac operating systems, then are calls to `net5.0` APIs type forwarded to individual operating systems' implementations of `net5.0`?

Comment: Which version of the net standard library are you using? From the [StreamWriter Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0#applies-to), this class applies to .net core and Xamarin.Mac,so, for the question 1 and 2,I think this method (.net core application) works well on Windows and Linux, for the question 3, if you are using the .net framework, since it is not cross-platform, the application will not work well on other OS. For .NET 5, see .NET 5 and .NET Standard later in [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Comment: Thanks for the response @ZhiLv. I used `StreamWriter` just as an example to illustrate a type which could vary depending on the OS platform.